# Why is de-dupe feature of ZFS not working with FreeBSD 8.2

Tags: freebsd, zfs, deduplication

I have FreeBSD 8.2 installed on AMD/64 with 3 GB RAM and 690 GB pooled HD under ZFS. I have two copies of an identical file (180 MB video) in same directory and yet df -h indicates that both are using storage.  I thought de-dupe was "built-in" with ZFS. Have I configured something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeBSD 8.2 only supports ZFS v15, but dedupe requires at least v21. [Link](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS)

I think that dedupe is coming with FreeBSD 8.3.

Other considerations:

- Depending on your pool setup, dedupe doesn't necessarily happen in real time.